# Elementary example of Baire spaces whose product is not Baire

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, forcing, baire-category

It is known that there are Baire spaces $X$ and $Y$ whose product is not Baire, the simplest construction I know is due to Cohen and goes as follow:

Let $S$ be a stationary subset of $\omega_1$, then forcing with the poset $\Bbb P_S$ of countable subsets of $S$ closed in $\omega_1$ ordered by $p\leq q$ iff $q\subseteq p$ and $(p\setminus q)\cap(\cup q)=\varnothing$ adds a club contained in $S$ to $\omega_1$. The proof of this fact shows that $\Bbb P_S$ is ${<\omega_1}$-distributive (hence Baire in the topology whose open sets are the initial segments). Now let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two disjoint clubs in $\omega_1$, then the poset $\Bbb P_{S_1}\times\Bbb P_{S_2}$ is not Baire otherwise forcing with it would add two disjoint clubs to $\omega_1$.

The whole proof uses a bunch of set theoretic facts:

- forcing with a ${<\kappa}$-distributive poset does not add sequences of length ${<\kappa}$ to the ground model.
- the filter $G\times H$ is $\Bbb P\times\Bbb Q$-generic over $M$ iff $G$ is $\Bbb P$-generic over $M$ and $H$ is $\Bbb Q$-generic over $M[G]$.
- If $\Bbb P$ and $\Bbb Q$ are separative posets then $\Bbb P\times\Bbb Q$ is Baire in $M$ iff $\Bbb P$ is Baire in $M$ and for every filter $G$ which is $\Bbb P$-generic over $M$, $\Bbb Q$ is Baire in $M[G]$.

There is another construction due to Kunen and Fleissner who, for every cardinal $\kappa$, constructed a family $\{X_\alpha\mid \alpha<\kappa\}$ of metrizable Baire spaces such that $\prod_{\alpha<\kappa}X_\alpha$ is nowhere Baire, meaning that it contains a countable family of dense open sets whose intersection is empty, while for every $\lambda<\kappa$, $\prod\{X_\alpha\mid\alpha\neq\lambda\}$ is Baire. This construction also uses stationary sets and set theoretic tools.

Suppose I want to show an example of two Baire spaces $X$ and $Y$ whose product is not Baire to a person who knows point-set topology but not a lot of set theory, is there a simple explicit construction of two spaces with that property? (Bonus points is the spaces are metrizable, or $X=Y$ or $X\times Y$ is nowhere Baire)

Comment: I wasn't sure whether the tags "set-theory" and "forcing" are appropriate, since I'm explicitly trying to avoid them, should I remove them?

Comment: It's a difficult idea. Why do you expect to have a nice elementary example?

Comment: @Asaf I'm using elementary to mean not explicitly set theoretic, not necessarily easy. I don't know if there's good reason to expect such an example to exist, but often topology counterexamples to point-set statements outside of set theoretic topology are explicit constructions of some obscure space, so I'm hoping that something like that can be done here too. For example it seems easy to show that arbitrary products of Baire spaces need not be Baire without involving much set theory

Comment: Bonus points for $X=Y$? If $X$ and $Y$ are Baire spaces whose product is not Baire, then isn't $X+Y$ a Baire space whose square is not Baire?

Comment: Oh of course you're right @bof

Comment: If $X$ is a Baire space whose square is not Baire, then the Banach–Mazur game on $X$ must be undetermined (or is the word indeterminate?), i,e., neither player has a winning strategy. I wonder how "non-set-theoretic" the construction of an undetermined game can be?

Comment: Which game are you referring to exactly @bof? I'm not very familiar with topological games, isn't the Banach-Mazur game relative to a subset of $X$?

Comment: Many spaces are Baire for a stronger reason: e.g. the strong Choquet game is won for player 2. And that property *is* productive. So we need "marginally Baire" spaces (not the easy completely metrisable, or locally compact Hausdorff ones etc.) which makes it more sensible they'd be hard to build. The "natural" examples won't do.

Comment: Interesting papers? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.06197.pdf https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/449c/ba72895944c9801db737daca5885b215f822.pdf

Comment: Maybe "Banach–Mazur game" was the wrong name, maybe it's called the "Choquet game". Let $G_X$ be the following game on a topological space $X$. First Black chooses a nonempty open set $B_1\subseteq X$; then White chooses a nonempty open set $W_1\subseteq B_1$; then Black chooses a n.o.s. $B_2\subseteq W_1$; then White chooses a n.o.s. $W_2\subseteq B_2$; and so on. Black wins if $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n=\emptyset$, White wins if $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n\ne\emptyset$. Black has a winning strategy in $G_X$ if and only if $X$ is not a Baire space.

Comment: $X$ is a Baire space if and only if Black has no winning strategy in $G_X$. "White has a winning strategy in $G_X$" is stronger than "$X$ is a Baire space". If White has winning strategies in $G_X$ and $G_Y$, then White has a winning strategy in $G_{X\times Y}$. If White has a winning strategy in $G_X$, and if $Y$ is a Baire space, then $X\times Y$ is a Baire space. [H. E. White, Jr., Topological spaces that are $\alpha$-favorable for a player with perfect information, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 50 (1975), 477–492](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-050-01/S0002-9939-1975-0367941-0/).

Comment: @Henno,bof: (can't ping both, that's annoying) A lot of interesting things to think about, thanks! I appreciate now why it may just be an inherently difficult question